# How can I solve responsive slider css problem?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, slider, hamburger-menu

Due to responsive css properties, slider transitions don't work when I click. The z-index feature works when the slider is featured, but this time the hamburger menu lags behind.

```
<html lang="en">
 <head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <title>AlgoRhythmApp</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="home.css"/>
   <script src="home.js" defer></script>
    <div class='background'>
     <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
     <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
     <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@200&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    </div>
 </head>
  <body>
    <header class="header">
        <div class="navigation">
        <input type="checkbox"
        class="toggle-menu">
        <div class="hamburger"></div>
        <div class="logo">
            <a href="#">
             <img src="images/AlgoRithmApp_logo.png" alt="">
            </a>
        </div>
          <ul class="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Anasayfa</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Kılavuzlar</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Vakalar</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Algoritmalar</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Görüntülemeler</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
    </header>
  </body>
    <div class="section full-height over-hide px-4 px-sm-0">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row full-height justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-lg-10 col-xl-8 align-self-center padding-tb">
                    <div class="section mx-auto text-center slider-height-padding">
                        <input class="ch frst" type="radio" id="slide-1" name="slider" checked/>
                        <label for="slide-1"></label>
                        <input class="ch scnd" type="radio" name="slider" id="slider-2"/>
                        <label for="slider-2"></label>
                        <input class="ch thrd" type="radio" name="slider" id="slider-3"/>
                        <label for="slider-3"></label>
                        <input class="ch foth" type="radio" name="slider" id="slider-4"/>
                        <label for="slider-4"></label>
                  <input class="ch fifth" type="radio" name="slider" id="slider-5"/>
                        <label for="slider-5"></label>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <span>ALGORİTMALAR</span>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <span>PULMOLER EMBOLİ</span>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <span>ESC STEMİ</span>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <span>ESC STEMİ</span>
                            </li>
              <li>
                <span>ESC STEMİ</span>
                </li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</html>
  
//////CSS CODE///////

body {
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    border:0px;
    right: 0px;
    left:0px;
    /*box-sizing: border-box;*/
}
.header {
    position: relative;
    width: 92vw;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    top:20px;
    border: 5px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: #c0392b;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #8e44ad, #c0392b);  
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #8e44ad, #c0392b);
    display: block;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0px 5px;
    /*background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.08);*/
    backdrop-filter: blur(20px);
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.logo a {
    display: block;
}

.logo a img {
    display: block;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
.navigation {
    display: flex;
    padding-left: 15px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 3;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}
.menu {
    display: flex;
    /*justify-content: flex-end;*/
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    z-index: 1;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
.menu li {
    list-style-type: none;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    z-index: 2;
}
.menu li a {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    padding: 40px 25px;
    font-size:18px;
    line-height: 1;
    transition: 0.3s;
}
.menu li a:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 -5px 0px #fff inset,
    500px 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.03) inset;
    padding: 35px 25px 45px 25px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
.hamburger {
    position: relative;
    width: 25px;
    height: 2.5px;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 10px;
    cursor:pointer;
    z-index: 4;
    transition: 0.3s;
}
.hamburger:before,
.hamburger:after {
    position: absolute;
    height: 3px;
    right: 0;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 10px;
    transition: 00.3s;
    content: '';
}
.hamburger:before {
  top: -10px;
  width:25px;
}
.hamburger:after {
  top: 10px;
  width: 25px;
}
.toggle-menu {
    position: absolute;
    width: 30px;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 4;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0;
}
.hamburger,
.toggle-menu {
    display: none;
}
.navigation {
  position: relative;
}

.navigation input:checked ~ .hamburger {
    background:transparent;
}
.navigation input:checked ~ .hamburger::before{
    top:0;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    width:30px;
}
.navigation input:checked ~ .hamburger:after{
    top:0;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    width:30px;
}

.navigation input:checked ~ .menu {
    display:block;
    transform: translateX(300px);
    box-shadow: -20px 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03) ;
}
a {
    cursor: pointer;
}
a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.section{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
.full-height{
  min-height: 100vh;
}
.over-hide{
  overflow: hidden;
}
.padding-tb{
  padding: 10px 0;
}
[type="radio"]:checked,
[type="radio"]:not(:checked){
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
}
.ch:checked + label,
.ch:not(:checked) + label{
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 15px 10px;
  /*left:5%;*/
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 3px solid #bdc3c7;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
  background-image: url('images/dna.jpg');
  animation: border-transform 6s linear infinite alternate forwards;
    -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
    -moz-animation-play-state: paused;
    animation-play-state: paused;
}
.ch.scnd + label{
  background-image: url('images/pulmoner_emboli.jpg');
    animation: border-transform 6s linear infinite alternate forwards;
    -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
    -moz-animation-play-state: paused;
    animation-play-state: paused;
}
.ch.thrd + label{
  background-image: url('images/esc_stemi.jpg');
    animation: border-transform 6s linear infinite alternate forwards;
    -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
    -moz-animation-play-state: paused;
    animation-play-state: paused;
}
.ch.foth + label{
  background-image: url('images/esc_stemi.jpg');
    animation: border-transform 6s linear infinite alternate forwards;
    -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
    -moz-animation-play-state: paused;
    animation-play-state: paused;
}
.ch.fifth + label{
  background-image: url('images/esc_stemi.jpg');
    animation: border-transform 6s linear infinite alternate forwards;
    -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
    -moz-animation-play-state: paused;
    animation-play-state: paused;
}

.ch:checked + label{
  box-shadow: 0 8px 25px 0 rgba(16,39,112,.3);
  transform: scale(1.3);
    -webkit-animation-play-state: running;
    -moz-animation-play-state: running;
    animation-play-state: running;
}

@keyframes border-transform{
  0%,100% { border-radius: 63% 37% 54% 46% / 55% 48% 52% 45%; } 
  14% { border-radius: 40% 60% 54% 46% / 49% 60% 40% 51%; } 
  28% { border-radius: 54% 46% 38% 62% / 49% 70% 30% 51%; } 
  42% { border-radius: 61% 39% 55% 45% / 61% 38% 62% 39%; } 
  56% { border-radius: 61% 39% 67% 33% / 70% 50% 50% 30%; } 
  70% { border-radius: 50% 50% 34% 66% / 56% 68% 32% 44%; } 
  84% { border-radius: 46% 54% 50% 50% / 35% 61% 39% 65%; } 
} 

.slider-height-padding {
  padding-top: 440px;
  justify-content: center;
}

.slider-height-padding ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 90vw;
  padding-left: 3vw;
  z-index: 0;
}
.slider-height-padding ul li {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background-color: #8e44ad;
  list-style: none;
  z-index: 0;
  list-style: none;
  height: 400px;
  border: 5px solid #bdc3c7;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-image: url('images/dna.jpg');
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 16px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  line-height: 2.7;
  color: #343434;
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 25px 0 rgba(16,39,112,.1);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.slider-height-padding ul li span {
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
}
.slider-height-padding ul li:nth-child(2) {
  background-image: url('images/pulmoner_emboli.jpg');
}
.slider-height-padding ul li:nth-child(3) {
  background-image: url('images/esc_stemi.jpg');
}
.slider-height-padding ul li:nth-child(4) {
  background-image: url('images/esc_stemi.jpg');
}
.slider-height-padding ul li:nth-child(5) {
  background-image: url('images/esc_stemi.jpg');
}
.ch.frst:checked ~ ul li:nth-child(1) {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
  border-radius: 16px;
}
.ch.scnd:checked ~ ul li:nth-child(2) {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
  border-radius: 16px;
}
.ch.thrd:checked ~ ul li:nth-child(3) {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
  border-radius: 16px;
}
.ch.foth:checked ~ ul li:nth-child(4) {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
  border-radius: 16px;
}
.ch.fifth:checked ~ ul li:nth-child(5) {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
  border-radius: 16px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
    .hamburger,
    .toggle-menu {
    display: block;
    }
    .header {
        justify-content: flex-start;
        margin: 0 0 0 0;
        padding-right: 0;
        padding-left: 0;
        border-radius: 0;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        width: 100%;
        position: relative;
    }

    .logo a img {
        display: block;
        padding-right: 0;
    }

    .menu {
        display: inline;
        justify-content: start;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        position: absolute;
        left: -340px;
        top: 0;
        background: rgb(171, 39, 2);
        width: 300px;
        height: 100vh;
        margin:0px 0px;
        padding-top: 65px;
    }
    .menu li {
        width:100%;
    }
    .menu li a,
    .menu li a:hover {
        font-size:18px;
        box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(219, 179, 179, 0.059);
    }
    .slider-height-padding {
      position: relative;
     padding-top: 340px;
     z-index: -1;
    }
   .slider-height-padding ul {
     position: absolute;
     z-index: -1;
    }  
    .slider-height-padding ul li {
     height: 300px;
     position: absolute;
     font-size: 13px;
     z-index: -1;
    }
}
```

I tried throwing the slider back with z-index:-1 in css, but this time it didn't work when I clicked on the slider transitions.

Comment: Your images are linked locally and we can't see a working example. If you could upload a working example either here, jsfiddle.net or a like site it would be easier to help you.

Comment: Removing the `zindex` from `@media screen and (max-width: 992px) .slider-height-padding` is working for me.